# How I can get the number of line and column for each token in antlr4?

Tags: java, antlr4

I am new with antlr4 ... I search a lot to get number of line and column for each token in antlr4 ... I have a well knewoleadge on flex and bison and I make a complete compiler for php with flex and bison ... in flex and bison I was get the number of line and column by a simple code :

in bison.y I define struct  :

```
    struct R{
        int i;
        float f;
        char c;
        char* str;
        int myLineNo;
        int myColno;

        }r;

namespace_name_parts: // rule 
      T_STRING {

 $<Expre>$=new var_dec($<r.str>1,$<r.myLineNo>1,$<r.myColno>1);

};
```

and in flex.l I write :

```
int lineNo = 1;
int colNo = 1;
"while"                   {

                               yylval.r.myLineNo= lineNo; 
                               yylval.r.myColno = colNo; 
                               colNo += strlen(yytext); 
                               return T_WHILE ;         
                          }
```

this way I can get the line of number and column with flex and bison ... 
NOTE : I need the line of number and column  for print my own type checking error

so can help me to get the number of line and column for each token in antlr4

Comment: The [`Token` interface](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Token.html) has all the methods you need: `getLine()` and `getCharPositionInLine()`.

Comment: ok ... can give me sample how to use this interface ?@Lucas Trzesniewski

Comment: Nope, I won't teach you the very basics of ANTLR, this site is *not* for this. [Read the docs](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/index.md), the usage should be *pretty* obvious.

Comment: ok thank you ... it very useful @ Lucas Trzesniewski

Answer (score 1):

Use an [error listener](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BaseErrorListener.html) to get notified about syntax errors. The principle is very simple. Create your own descendant and override the `reportError()` function. In order to put your listener class in place call `parser.addErrorListener()`.

Comment: If my answer helped you then accept it by clicking the check mark on the left. If you feel it is worth you can also upvote. Don't post "thanks"-only comments.